# Android Emulator does not respond to HelloWorld app

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator

We are trying to build an android app using cordova with the help of [this](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface) link .
When we boot the emulator using `cordova emulate android` command then on emulator we get the error message as

> Process system isnt responding Do you want to? (Wait or Ok)

and after that when we click on the `HelloWorld` app a white blank screen appears with the error

> Unfortunately HelloWorld has stopped

We are getting the below messages in logcat while running my app on the emulator

1) activityManager : force removing activityrecord app died, no saved state error

2) zygote : process 1261 exited due to signal 6 error in logcat

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

can you try "cordova run android" if no device is connected it will start emulator for you. This might help you. Thanks.

Comment: We tried using this command to solve this problem but it doesn't work.